# how to setup email functionality in azure environment

Tags: azure

Hi can any1 tell me how to implement email functionality in azure without using sendgrid or any other 3rd party all. Can we have service bus to connect azure and exchange server to send emails.is it possible.or do we have exchange server web services to be accesses in azure and sends
 email

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not about **having** to use a third party, it is about the security and firewall implications — particularly with corporate security overlords. An exchange server can have outgoing smtp (even with username and password) enabled, and it is easy for any application (including those running on Azure) to send outgoing SMTP. The problem that you will invariably run into is that the perimeter security around the exchange server will not allow smtp from a public ip address (hackers frequently scan for open port 25, so that they can relay spam through unsuspecting mail servers). Windows Azure (roles and websites) cannot use a fixed (outgoing) ip, so firewall rules cannot be created.

Your options are:

1. Setup a VPN with your corporate network, so your Azure instance will send from a private IP address.
2. Run a mail relay service on an Azure VM. The VM can have an infinite lease on an IP address, so won't change (much). There are simple and cheap mail transfer agent services that run on Linux.
3. Use any 'ol smtp server. If you're not sending much out, you could use Google or even outlook.com. Outlook.com allows you to configure accounts that are hosted elsewhere, so you should be able to use smtp with your windows live id (Microsoft account).

I would avoid writing complicated code and services that use something like service bus. System.Net.Mail should be used to send to an smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've seen done in the past was to have the Windows Azure app put a message on a queue, along with optionally some larger data (attachments, large body text, etc.) in a blob.  That gets the data stored in Windows Azure storage.  From there, an on-premises app (e.g. Windows Service) could pull the queue and blob data, construct an email message, and send it to the on-premises Exchange server.

If you need everything to be cloud-hosted, then I would think you should be able to connect your Windows Azure apps to an Exchange web service endpoint (assuming you can properly secure that and make the web service connection).